# Game Center friend invites not working in iOS 10

Tags: messages, ios, game-center

When sending a Game Center Friend Invite from the Matchmaking screen of an App the invited player cannot join the Game.

When clicking on the Game Center Invite in iMessage it will open the Settings App instead of launching the Game.

Is this a problem on my end or is it a problem at Apples end.
Does anyone else experience this problem? 
If not. 
How can you fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Many Game Center's features were removed from the Game Center service itself so they still wouldn't work, including adding friends, even if you have Ios 10 . Now, you can see just the rankings and the goals of the game; you can also invite and challenge your friends only through iMessage, and only if the game supports it.